# Prove that the sum of the probability of all sequence lengths is equal to one in a Markov Chain with non uniform end state probabilities.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I want to prove that in a Markov chain the sum of all sequence probabilities is equal to one.
$$  \sum_{L=1}^{\infty} P(\lvert x \rvert = L) = 1 $$
There is a beginning state $\alpha$ and an end state $\omega$ through which each sequence has to go. Each state has a probability of going to the end state: $p_{s_i;\omega}$. When the  $p_{s_i;\omega}$'s are uniform the statement is easy to prove with the help of a geometric series. How to prove this when the $p_{s_i;\omega}$ are non-uniform.

Comment: The question is quite vague. First, how do you define $x$? Is it a stopped Markov chain? And what does "an end state $\omega$ through which each sequence has to go" mean? Is there a definition? But maybe I just don't see what you mean.

Comment: @GrafZahl $x$ is a sequence of observations $x_1,...,x_L$ of labeled states in the Markov chain. It is not a stopped Markov chain. Each sequence has to start at the $\alpha$ state and each sequence has to end at the end state $\omega$. That means that each state has a transition probability from itself to the end state that is equal or bigger than zero. Also the end state has no transition probabilities.

Comment: So $\omega$ is an absorbing state, correct? Is it the only absorbing state? If so, then $$\{\text{Being absorbed in } \omega\}=\bigcup_{L=1}^{\infty}\{|x|=L\}$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling All sequences $x$ must end in $\omega$ so I think your statement is correct. And yes there is only one end state.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I think you are misunderstanding something. Maybe I worded it in a weird way. So say you have a random path $\pi$ from $\alpha$ to $\omega$. This path has a length $L$. What is the probability that $L=1$? What is the probability that $L=2$? So the sum of these probabilities is 1. I want to prove this, I don't think what you did is equivalent to this.

Comment: Is $L$ the *smallest* length of such a path? So if $\pi$ has length $L=2$ then would we have $$X_0=\alpha,X_1\neq \omega,X_2=\omega?$$ Otherwise, if $L$ is the length of any path that starts at $\alpha$ and ends in $\omega$, then $$\{|X|=k\}\subseteq \{|X|=k+1\}$$ for any $k\geq 1$

Comment: @MatthewPilling What do you mean by $L$ being the smallest, we want to consider all paths of all lengths. Yes if $\pi$ has length 2 then the path is indeed the one you wrote. The bottom statement is also correct I think.

Comment: If $L$ is the length of the smallest path connecting $\alpha$ and $\omega$ then $X_{L}=\omega$ and $X_k\neq \omega$ for all $k<L$. This means $\{L=l_1\}$ and $\{L=l_2\}$ are disjoint whenever $l_1\neq l_2$.

Comment: @areobe To define the "length" of your Markov chain properly it might help to say $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov chain with $P(X_0=\alpha)=1$ and $p_{\omega,\omega}=1$. This means it starts a.s. in $\alpha$ and if it reaches $\omega$ it will stay there forever. Now, what you call length would then be defined as the event $\inf \{n\geq 0:X_n=\omega\}$. Is this a definition that would work for you? Otherwise you should clear some things up.

Two additional questions: What do you know about the $p_{s_i,\omega}$ and where are the $s_i$ from?

Comment: @GrafZahl Yes that definition would be great for the problem.

Comment: Then the answer depends on the rest of the setting. If you consider the state space to be finite and all $p_{s_i,\omega}>0$ the sum should equal $1$, otherwise there should be counterexamples.

Comment: @GrafZahl State space is finite and all $p_{s_i,\omega} > 0$.

Comment: If you know for sure that the chain will eventually end in the only absorbing state $\omega$ then $$P(\text{Absorbed in } \omega)=1$$ Writing $\{\text{Absorbed in }\omega\}$ as a disjoint union $\bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty}\{L=l\}$ yields $$1=P\big(\text{Absorbed in }\omega\big)=P\Bigg(\bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty}P(L=l)\Bigg)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}P(L=l)$$ Notice here that I denoted the length of the smallest path as $L$ instead of $|X|$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I think you accidentally wrote $P$ instead of curly brackets or am I missing something

Comment: @areobe yes. The expression $P\Bigg(\bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty}P(L=l)\Bigg)$ should actually be $P\Bigg(\bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty}\{L=l\}\Bigg)$. Good eye!